# Translating database string in Django

Tags: django

If I have a database table containing countries names, and I am using `{% trans country_name %}`, when iterating over a QuerySet in my template, how can I add the countries names to the po file?

Since it is not showing up as static string anywhere in the django project, it is not showing up on the po file generated by "makemessages".

Comment: `makemessages` can't magically extract those values from the database, so you'll have to manually add them to the `.po` file. Perhaps you could write a management command which does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

For translating database contents you can use [django-hvad](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad)